# R formula paste condition

Tags: r, vector, conditional-statements, formula, paste

I want to paste a formula in R out of two different vectors which has a condition. Pasting a formula out of a vector containing the coefficients is ok but I don't have a clue how to add the conditional terms

I have tried to manage the problem with paste and paste0

```
f1 <- c("x1", "x2", "x3")
f2 <- c("x3", "x4", "x5")
```

the result should be
`y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 | x3 + x4 + x5`

I have to manage a big dataset with > 100 coefficients so typing it manually is no real option.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might be what you are looking for:

```r
f1 <- c("x1", "x2", "x3") 
f2 <- c("x3", "x4", "x5")
paste("y ~ ",paste(f1, collapse = " + "),"|",paste(f2, collapse = " + "))

#output
#[1] "y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 | x3 + x4 + x5"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help@LouisMP! I tried to paste the conditional part to an existing formula... your solution works just fine

Answer (score 0):

We could put the terms into a list,

```
terms <- list(f1, f2)
```

and use `reformulate()`.

```
fo <- reformulate(paste(sapply(terms, paste, collapse=" + "), collapse=" | "), response="y")
fo
# y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 | x3 + x4 + x5
```

The benefit is this:

```
class(fo)
# [1] "formula"
```

#### Data

```
f1 <- c("x1", "x2", "x3")
f2 <- c("x3", "x4", "x5")
```

Comment: Hi @jay.sf! Thank you for your tip - I didn't know about the reformulate function till now! Thx!